# node-soap wssecuritycert with private root certificate authority

Tags: node.js, web-services, certificate, soapui, node-soap

Background information.

My company requires certs to access soap services.  They require me to submit a csr to them and they sign it with their root CA.  they then send back the signed certificate with their root ca certificate.

Portacle
I've got this working in SoapUI by using the Program Portacle to import the pem file i got back and to import the root cert (the CA cert) I then use Portacle to export the keypair with private key and certificates in pem format.  oh and I also secure the keypair with a password.

SoapUI
In SoapUI I add the exported pem file to the Keystores area under WS-Security Configurations along with the password I used in the Portacle step.  I then configure the Outgoing WS-Security Configurations by adding a WSS Signature entry with the following config.
   Keystore the one I setup above
   Password the password I setup above
   Binary Security Token
   Signature Algorithm:  rsa-sha1
   Signature Canonicalization: default
   Digest Algorithm: sha1
   Use Single Certificate: yes

In my soap requests I use authorization: Basic and I select my WSS configuration for OutgoingWSS: that I setup above.

In node-soap.  I'm unsure how to set this up.  I've tried using the .pem file I exported from Portacle for both the privatekey and publick key and putting in my password.  node-soap takes this but I get back and error: authorizationError: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'  I've tried breaking out the pem file into private key and cert and I've tried using syswide-cas to load the root-ca cert into node I've also tried using ssl-root-cas to load the root-ca into node and as a last attempt I tried adding process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; but still get the same error every time.  not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Try using .p12 or .pkcs12 files.
As per documentation (https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#outgoing-soap-headers):- pfx: A string or Buffer containing the private key, certificate and CA certs of the server in PFX or PKCS12 format. (Mutually exclusive with the key, cert and ca options.)